# I am getting this syntax error " missing ';' " in hyperledger composer. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: hyperledger

I have just started working on the Hyperledger composer. I am trying to create a car auction business network but I am getting this error : "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement".

How do I solve that?
Also how do I access the underlying code for the fabric?

Comment: There might be a syntax error in your Javascript code, check [SyntaxError: missing ; before statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement)

Comment: Thanks, but where can I access the code on the hyper ledger?